# Ansible create list of item base on other list of item

Tags: list, ansible

I have json file (I can't change what is in json file)

```
{
    "application": {
        ...,
        "VS": [
            {
                "LTM": "server1",
                "ltm_vs": "VS_1",
                "address": "IP",
                "port": "80",
                "link": "/Common/link"
            },
            {
                "LTM": "server1",
                "ltm_vs": "VS_2",
                "address": "IP",
                "port": "8081",
                "link": "/Common/link"
            },
            {
                "LTM": "server1",
                "ltm_vs": "VS_3",
                "address": "IP",
                "port": "443",
                "link": "/Common/link"
            }
        ] 
    }
}
```

I need to take that file to create list with only some information.

So presently I import the json file like that:

```
...
  tasks:    

    - name: Include application information
      include_vars:
        file: path/file.json

...
```

and was create a variables list application.VS I need to map attribute LTM to server and ltm_vs to virtual_server and create list:

```
VS_lst:
  - { server: "server1", virtual_server: "VS_1" }
  - { server: "server1", virtual_server: "VS_2" }
  - { server: "server1", virtual_server: "VS_3" }
```

I have try with that:

```
    - name: Add variables
      set_fact:
        VS_lst: >- 
          {{ VS_lst +[{
            'server': "{{ item.LTM }}",
            'virtual_server': "{{ item.ltm_vs }}"
          }]
          }}
      with_items: "{{ application.VS }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{VS_lst}}"
```

the output:

```
TASK [Add variables] *******************************************************************************
ok: [GTM_Server] => (item={'LTM': 'server1', 'ltm_vs': 'VS_1', 'address': 'IP', 'port': '80', 'link': '/Common/link'})
ok: [GTM_Server] => (item={'LTM': 'server1', 'ltm_vs': 'VS_2', 'address': 'IP', 'port': '8081', 'link': '/Common/link'})
ok: [GTM_Server] => (item={'LTM': 'server1', 'ltm_vs': 'VS_3', 'address': 'IP', 'port': '443', 'link': '/Common/link'})

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************
ok: [GTM_Server] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "server": "server1",
            "virtual_server": "VS_2"
        },
        {
            "server": "{{ item.LTM }}",
            "virtual_server": "{{ item.ltm_vs }}"
        },
        {
            "server": "{{ item.LTM }}",
            "virtual_server": "{{ item.ltm_vs }}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the fixed version

```
- name: Add variables
  set_fact:
    VS_lst: "{{ VS_lst|default([]) +
                [{'server': item.LTM,
                  'virtual_server': item.ltm_vs}] }}"
  loop: "{{ application.VS }}"
```

There are also other options. For example, it's possible to use *json_query*

```
- set_fact:
    VS_lst: "{{ application.VS|
                json_query('[].{server: LTM,
                                virtual_server: ltm_vs}') }}"
- debug:
    var: VS_lst
```

give

```
"VS_lst": [
    {
        "server": "server1", 
        "virtual_server": "VS_1"
    }, 
    {
        "server": "server1", 
        "virtual_server": "VS_2"
    }, 
    {
        "server": "server1", 
        "virtual_server": "VS_3"
    }
]
```

Without *json_query*, this task *"creates a list of items base on another list of items"* and gives the same result

```
- set_fact:
    VS_lst: "{{ VS_lst|default([]) +
                [dict(dictionary_keys|
                      zip(selected_params|
                          map('extract', item)))] }}"
  loop: "{{ application.VS }}"
  vars:
    selected_params: ['LTM','ltm_vs']
    dictionary_keys: ['server', 'virtual_server']
```